# Private iPhone App, without App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am developing an iPhone app for a private company. It contains business critical data and should only be able to use for this company.

Do I still need to go via the App store? Is there not a private way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS installing apps without app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848916/ios-installing-apps-without-app-store)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your company can [pay $299/yr to join the enterprise program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/) which allows you to deploy app without going through the AppStore.

You can create Ad Hoc distributions for ≤ 100 users.

You can jailbreak all the target iPhones and do whatever you want.

Comment: Jailbreaking an iPhone when business critical data is in there is a bad idea.

Comment: +1 for enterprise program. Then you can use http://www.appaloosa-store.com to deploy the application to your employees. Basically, it's a private app store (works also with android apps).

Comment: Enterprise program is not required in order to do Ad Hoc Distribution, Developer program is enough: http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios

Answer (score 5):

If you want the employee to download your apps over the air without listing each employee's UDID you want to subscribe to enterprise program.

However, even with you enterprise license you will have to distribute by yourself your apps to employees. To ease your distribution, you can use private stores solutions like [Appaloosa](http://www.appaloosa-store.com).

Answer (score 2):

You may test & love [testflightapp](https://testflightapp.com/).

Comment: http://www.hockeyapp.net   is even more sophisticated, since you can use their automatical crashreporting, thats far above Apple's crashreporting

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay completely private (apart of submiting the UDIDs to Apple), then build your own OTA-server. It's done in a few minutes, only registered UDIDs can use the app, and no 3rd party has access to your ipa.

[Example](http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/)

Comment: Does this still apply today, 6 years after the article was written?

Comment: I haven't down this since a year or so, bit I don't see a reason why it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the Enterprise program. I have no personal experience with it, but as I understand it, it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Enterprise might not be available for smaller companies. A friend of mine tried to sign up the enterprise program and wasn't approved