# iOS installing apps without app store

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

is there any LEGAL way (w/o jailbreak) to install iOS application to iOS device (ipad, iphone, ipod) without publishing to application store? For example - application for closed group of users (admins/moderators etc of some web application).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone app without AppStore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore)

Comment: See also [Private iPhone App, without App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583920/private-iphone-app-without-app-store)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking legal information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice. Questions regarding law (including technology law) can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apple supports "Ad-Hoc" application distribution for exactly this purpose, but it is limited to 100 devices. If you have an Enterprise developer account, you can do Ad-hoc distribution within your organization, as well.

[iOS Developer Distribution Options](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html)
[iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Comment: In addition, you can use sites like [testflightapp.com](http://testflightapp.com/) to help with your Ad-Hoc distributions. It will notify your users when there are updates available and allows them to install updates over the air.

The site is intended for use as a beta app distribution system, but can be used for small Ad-Hoc groups.

Comment: There is http://www.appaloosa-store.com which is more dedicated to enterprise distribution.

Answer (score 10):

You need to apply for a Enterprise/Corporate development license with Apple. Then they provide the option to deploy without the app store.

<s>The minimum amount of employees is high though (about 500 I think).</s> **EDIT:** The employee restriction has been removed!

See this link for more info: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: That 500+ employees requirement is dropped now! Any company can register for the Enterprise Program now.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, ahdoc distribution allows you to installed on upto 100 devices (including the ones you use for development), all you have to do is have the paid for developer account (the standard $99 one).

Here's one explanation, but there are loads of articles around on the subject:

http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/

**Update Summer 2013**: The limit now seems to have been increased from 100 devices to 200 devices.

Comment: The link to the [guide itself](http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/) referenced by the C|Net article may be more useful.

Comment: Good point John, thanks - I've updated my answer with that.

Comment: Don't the ad-hoc profiles expire at some point?

Comment: Yes. So do enterprise ones, though you get a bit longer with those I think. It's easy to renew them though.

Answer (score 3):

Without jailbreaking, there are solutions for private market places which bypass the app store.

Some of the names of these companies are:

- Appaloosa
- EnterpriseAppZone
- apperian
- mobileiron
- appcentral

Answer (score 0):

https://music-vk.com/ - These guys somehow make it possible to install their app directly via a Safari link. It requires no usernames, no passwords. Just click and it is installed right away. Haven't figured out how they do it though

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/ - this is the answer, also it 's right answer for this question

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is. Search 'hip store' on google and click on the first result. When you get there you type what app you want. Then when the app comes up click 'tai xoung' then a pop up comes up click 'tai xoung' again and then it will take you to another screen with a loading bar and it will count down. Then you will click install.