# loading an iOS app to a device over the air

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS installing apps without app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848916/ios-installing-apps-without-app-store)

I have built an iOS app for a friend of mine who lives in a different city. I have a standard $99/year developer account that I used to build it. Is it possible to get it to his device over the air?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible with TestFlight:

https://www.testflightapp.com/

Haven't tried it myself yet, but it looks promising.

Comment: Yup, use TestFlight.  Perfect for setting up Beta testing or distribution to friends before you go live.

Comment: That's what the page says yes...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a number of ways you can do it. You have to provision his device to test it, and then you can send him the IPA file(Created by using Archive in XCode), and have him install it through iTunes. Alternatively, you can sign up at TestFlight(http://www.testflightapp.com) and do the same thing with TestFlight. We use TestFlight because we have multiple beta testers, and it's a very useful service.